Как в UNREAL ENGINE выделить на импортируемом ландшафте отдельный элемент?
На проект в Unreal Engine закачена карта открытого мира. Я занимаюсь установкой звуков ходьбы. Мне нужно выделить на ландшафте речку, чтобы применить к ней звуки ходьбы по воде. При попытке выделить отдельно воду (речку), ее выделить не получается - ландшафт разбивается по секторам: охватываются часть воды вместе с частью суши и прибрежной зоной. А мне нужно чтобы выделилась на карте только вода, чтобы в ее материале ввести физический материал. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно отделить воду отдельно от остальных структур карты, как сделать чтобы я мог внести нужные свойства звуков ходьбы конкретно под нее?

Вы уже задавали этот вопрос. Не плодите дубликаты
